# change interval of the LocationRequest depending on distance between current and some location

Tags: android, gps, location

I want to save battery by changing the interval of updates using the Fused Location API. As far from some location, bigger should be the interval.

```
public class service extends Service implements GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,LocationListener {
    private LocationRequest locationrequest;
    private LocationClient locationclient;



    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        int resp = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resp == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            locationclient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
            locationclient.connect();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Service Error " + resp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }



    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if(locationclient!=null)
            locationclient.disconnect();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onConnected");
        if (locationclient != null && locationclient.isConnected()) {
            locationrequest = LocationRequest.create();
            locationrequest.setInterval(5000);
            locationrequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            locationclient.requestLocationUpdates(locationrequest, this);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisconnected() {
        Log.i(TAG, "onDisconnected");


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onConnectionFailed");


    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(location!=null){
            double Lat=-34.922611;
            double Lng = 138.596161;
            Location Loc = new Location("");
            Loc.setLatitude(Lat);
            Loc.setLongitude(Lng);
            Float dist=location.distanceTo(Loc);
            String distance = Float.toString(dist);
            if (dist>100){
                Log.i("distance",distance);
                locationclient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
                locationrequest.setInterval(30000);
                locationrequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER);
                locationclient.requestLocationUpdates(locationrequest, this);

            }

            Log.i(TAG, "Location Request :" + location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude());


        }

    }
}
```

Unfortunately this is not working.. somebody knows why? or is there a better way to do that?
thanks

EDIT 1:
What I am getting as output is a locationrequest that behaves in the same way  before the change. If I call locationrequest.getInterval , the new interval will be show but the locationrequest will give me updates with the first interval.

Comment: you should explain how your code is failing: exactly what is happening and how that differs from your expectation.

Comment: @WoodrowBarlow how about now? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Fused Location API you can do something like:

```
mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                    .setInterval(INTERVAL)        
                    .setFastestInterval(FASTEST_INTERVAL);
```

Then when an event is triggered in your app and you want to change the intervals, you would call the same piece of code but just change the `INTERVAL` and `FASTEST_INTERVAL` values.
After you change them do no forget to update the Location Updates like so:

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
```

Comment: This works for me only if the initial value of INTERVAL and FASTEST_INTERVAL are the highest values the application uses. For example, if they're both 0, and I increase intervals, I see no difference. If they're 60000 say, and I decrease and increase up to that limit, I see a difference. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: @keshav.bahadoor try to `removeLocationUpdates` then `requestLocationUpdates` . It works in my case.

Comment: @MuhammadResnaRizkiPratama Somehow my google api client is disconnected when I try `removeLocationUpdates`. I'm calling this after its already connected and receiving locations

Comment: That solved my problem. There was no issues running by hand in the terminal but when it was started by supervisor, it just didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Use **removeLocationUpdates** before changing the interval
with **addOnCompleteListener** to make sure you unregistered the previous request, and re-init the LocationRequest object:

```
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
                    mLocationRequest.setInterval(5000);
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is most likely that you have another process that requests locations, and that your app just listenes along. The setInterval means only what your app requires, not what it gets. So if another process has a faster interval you will get faster location updates.

Check for example if you have a GoogleMap with the MyLocation layer enabled. The map will request its own locations.

Finally, the LocationClient is deprecated. Check the documentation for [FusedLocationApi](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html) to implement the correct current practice.